# how to access an objects element based on its name

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, single-page-application, javascript-objects

I have an observable array that I am capturing from the controller , its bringing out out the whole object when I use ko.mapping from js , how can I access an array element from the objects . At the moment it returns somethings"{"driverId":1,"driverName":"Simon Jenkins",}" how do I pick out just the name and not the ID or vice versa

```
    if (!pageViewModel.isAuthenticated()) return;
$.when(getSecureData("/api/vehicleDrivers/" + id))
.done(function (driverList) {
    driverList.unshift({ "driverId": 0, "driverName": "Please select a driver..." });
     pageViewModel.DriverVM.driverList(driverList);
     pageViewModel.vehicleVM.driverDetail.driverId(ko.mapping.fromJS(driverList));


    /*var List = driverList;
    List[0] = pageViewModel.VehicleVM.driverDetail.driverId;
    List[1] = pageViewModel.vehicleVM.driverDetail.driverName;*/
})
.fail(function (message) {
    $.msgbox(message);
});
```

}

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle of plunker? _At the moment it returns somethings"{"driverId":1,"driverName":"Simon Jenkins",}" how do I pick out just the name and not the ID or vice versa_ : you mean something like `.driverId` ?

Comment: @Grundy yes something like that

Comment: What exactly isn't working? I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore some properties when mapping, you can use the [ignore option](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#ignoring-certain-properties-using-ignore). If you want to specify which fields are included, you can preprocess with [`ko.utils.arrayMap`](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html)

```
var driverIdList = ko.utils.arrayMap(driverList, function (item) {
    return item.driverID;
});
```

Then you could use `ko.mapping` to convert that to observables, or just pass it to an observableArray.